# React Native Child Component update

Tags: react-native, components, rendering, parent-child, rerender

I'm trying to update the child component (that represents a listItem) when the user clicks on a Swipable button, in order to set it to "read". In my parent component "NotificationList.js" the data is being updated successfully and when I "console.log()" the data is updated. However, I want to change the ListItem background color, in spite of this state (read/not read). Internally on the child component, the update is working fine, but when I try to update it based on the parent component that data changes are not re-rendering on the child component.

I already tried to use "setState", "componentDidMount" and "componentWillReceiveProps". Probably one of this one should solve my question, but I might not have applied them correctly.

In summary, my problem is related to how to update a Child component listItem when I update my data object on the parent side?

Can someone give me some tips on how can I solve this situation?

I send some of my code bellows. Let me know if you might need for information on the current problem.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

**NotificationsList.js**

```
export default class NotificationsList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
                listViewData: this.props.datainfo,
        };
    }

   [.....]

render() {
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
                <SwipeListView
                    useFlatList
                    data={this.state.listViewData}
                    renderItem={ (data, rowMap) => (
                        <SwipeRow>
                            <View style={styles.rowBack}>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={ _ => {
                                this.updateReadState(data.item.key, rowMap);
                                }}>
                                <Text style={styles.backTextBlack}>{data.item.read == true ? "Unread" : "Read"}</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>

                            <NotificationsRow 
                                data={data.item}
                            />
                        </SwipeRow>
                    )}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

**NotificationsRow.js**

```
export default class NotificationsRow extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            datarow: this.props.data,
        };
    }

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>             
                    <View style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.datarow.read == true ? '#FFFFFF' : '#dddddd', }}>

                        <View style={ styles.listText }>                            
                            <View>
                                <Text style={ styles.messageText }> { this.state.datarow.message } </Text>
                                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={ () => {
                                    this.state.rowReadState = !this.state.rowReadState;
                                }}>
                                    <Image source={ this.state.datarow.read == true ? require('../images/readed.png') : require('../images/unread.png') } />
                                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The background color of the NotificationRow property is set by your internal component state. It's currently set by your constructor method and it's only when the instance of NotificationRow is created. Same goes for ComponentDidMount method. It's only triggered when component mounts.

There are a few ways to update your child's state.

1. don't use NotificationRow internal state - just pass the backgroundColor prop, or use it like: `backgroundColor: this.props.dataRow.read ? 'red' : 'blue`
2. If you really want to use internal state you can use `ComponentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` or `ComponentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)` to compare if the props have changed. Avoid using `ComponentWillRecieveProps` since it's going to be deprecated soon.

Comment: Thanks, @Žiga-kerec, I think I understood the tips you told me. 

I tried to implement them, but it is normal to when adding the "ComponentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) or ComponentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)", neither one of them is reached on the NotificationRow.js?

When I update the "read" on the NotificationList.js the JSON object is updated correctly, but It does not call the previous functions, in order to force the update.

Any other suggestion?

Comment: @Integer I just noticed that I've written the functions with the capital first letter. It should be `componentDidMount`. Otherwise, try as I said in the first point, use props directly without copying them to the internal state of the child component. You won't need to worry about syncing them in that case.

Comment: I guess I might be missing something @Žiga Kerec. Since the functions `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUpdate` inside the "NotifcationsRow.js" file are only being called on the first screen render.

I already changed, the "NoficationsRow.js" to use the "this.props".

Any clue of what I might be missing?